# Passing a custom component to material ui dialog that opens it

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to pass a custom component to a MUI Dialog in such way that it should open the Dialog itself and render its children.

```
const CustomDialog = ({children, someCustomComponent}) => {
 const handleClickOpen = () => {
  setOpen(true);
 };

 const handleClose = () => {
  setOpen(false);
 };

 return(
  <>
   {someCustomComponent} // use this component to call handleOpen/handleClose
   <Dialog>
    <DialogTitle>
    <DialogTItle>
    <DialogContent>{children}</DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>...</DialogActions>
   </Dialog>
  </>
 );

}

CustomDialog.propTypes = {
 someCustomComponent: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}
```

And then call it like this

```
<CustomDialog someCustomComponent={<h1>open</h1>}>
 {myDialogContent}
</CustomDialog>
```

Is this possible? So, essentially, I don't always want a button to open my Dialog. I want to have any component I pass to it to be able to open it.

This is kind of how this is done by using Button

```
 return(
  <>
   <Button onClick={handleClickOpen} />
   <Dialog>
   ...
```

but I want to pass any element to it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do it is with `React.cloneElement`

```js
const CustomDialog = ({ children, someCustomComponent }) => {
  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  // clone the component and add the onClick handler
  const customComponentClone = React.cloneElement(someCustomComponent, {
    onClick: handleClickOpen
  });

  return (
    <>
      {customComponentClone}
      <Dialog>
        <DialogTitle>
        <DialogTItle>
        <DialogContent>{children}</DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>...</DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </>
  );
}
```

This way you can use it like you mentioned

```js
<CustomDialog someCustomComponent={<h1>open</h1>}>
  {myDialogContent}
</CustomDialog>
```

Check here a [live version](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-goldwasser-eoz9of)

Comment: Thanks man! I didn't know how to achieve this! Glad to learn more!